# Combine multiple probability plots (using probplot in Matlab ) in a single figure for differently sized arrays

Tags: matlab

I am trying to obtain multiple probability plots in the same figure but I am unable to do the same. Could you please offer your help in this, Here is a sample code of what I have been trying to do

```
    cmap=colormap(jet(10));
    close;

    for pp = 1:10

    numelements = randi(10e4,1,1);    
    data = rand(numelements,1)*2;    


    figure(1);
    h1 = probplot('lognormal',data,'noref');
    set(h1(1),'marker','+','color',cmap(pp,:),'markersize',10);
    hold on;



    end
```

hold on doesn't work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create the figure only the first time, and get the handle to the created axis.  Then subsequent times you need to tell `probplot` to use that same axis, e.g.

```
cmap=colormap(jet(10));
close;

h1 = nan(1,10);  % Preallocate a vector to store all the line handles

for pp = 1:10

    numelements = randi(10e4,1,1);
    data = rand(numelements,1)*2;

    if pp == 1
        figure(1);
        h1(pp) = probplot('lognormal',data,'noref');
        ha = get(h1(pp),'Parent'); % get the handle to the created axis
    else
        h1(pp) = probplot(ha,'lognormal',data,'noref'); % reuse the same axis
    end

    set(h1(pp),'marker','+','color',cmap(pp,:),'markersize',10);

    hold on;  % This doesn't do anything and can be removed.
end
```